# Prevent Padding is Invalid Exception when Brute Forcing

Tags: .net, encryption, exception, cryptography, aes

Im using this code to decrypt AES data:

```
public static String decrypt(String ciphertext, String password)
{
    byte[] cipherdata = System.Convert.FromBase64String(ciphertext);

    byte[] iv = new byte[AESBlockSize * 4];
    Array.Copy(cipherdata, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length);

    byte[] input = new byte[cipherdata.Length - iv.Length];
    Array.Copy(cipherdata, iv.Length, input, 0, input.Length);

    Rfc2898DeriveBytes passwordDB = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, iv, PBKDF2Iterations);
    byte[] keyBytes = passwordDB.GetBytes(256 / 8);

    RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();

    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.ISO10126;

    ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, iv);

    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(input);
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

    byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[input.Length];

    int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);

    memoryStream.Close();
    cryptoStream.Close();

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
}
```

I get the exception `Padding is invalid and cannot be removed` on the call to `cryptoStream.Read`when the wrong password is supplied.

Is there any way to prevent this exception when using the wrong password, because I'm trying to make a brute-forcer, and the exceptions are very slow to handle.

Comment: Your question might already have been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11762/146622) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/604210/146622), among others...

Comment: Of course you can set the `PaddingMode` to none, but how will you test your password guess?

Comment: @Virtlink No it has not already been answered. Those people asks WHY they are getting the exception, I understand why, but want to know how I can prevent it.

Comment: @GregS If its the correct password a known string will be in the output.

Comment: Where is the encrypted data coming from?  Are you sure you have all of it?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469819/padding-is-invalid-and-cannot-be-removed-exception-while-decrypting-string-using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just brute forcing go ahead and set the `PaddingMode` to `None`, you will decrypt the last block with the padding included, which you can use in your recognition of the plaintext with whatever else you are checking.

Comment: Thanks, didnt realize it was so simple. It didn't make a big difference for performance, but it works.