# AES Padding cant be removed

Tags: c#, encryption, padding

### Description

I am using a slightly modified security class taken straight from codeproject.com, I am using it to encrypt/decrypt aes byte arrays.

I have tested that the key generation method in these produces the same key, and they are given the same password and salt. they also have the same IV

the error is always on the line after the `CryptoStream.Write` in the `AES_Decrypt` function

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed."

(yes i know having a static salt is bad, this is only for testing purposes)

### Solutions that didn't work

Paddingmode.Zeros
Paddingmode.None
.FlushFinalBlock();

### Related Questions

- ["Padding is invalid and cannot be removed" using AesManaged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604210/padding-is-invalid-and-cannot-be-removed-using-aesmanaged)
- [Padding is invalid and cannot be removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583112/padding-is-invalid-and-cannot-be-removed)
- [Padding is invalid and cannot be removed Exception while decrypting string using "AesManaged" C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469819/padding-is-invalid-and-cannot-be-removed-exception-while-decrypting-string-using)
- [Error RijndaelManaged, "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406135/error-rijndaelmanaged-padding-is-invalid-and-cannot-be-removed)

### Related Links

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d1788582-bf8c-43ec-a686-49647c359136/unexplained-cryptographicexception-padding-is-invalid?forum=netfxbcl
- http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/379525/Padding-is-invalid-and-cannot-be-removed-Exception

### Code

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
using System;

namespace FinexCore
{
    public class Security
    {
        /*
         * AES encrypt and decrypt from:
         * http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/769741/Csharp-AES-bits-Encryption-Library-with-Salt 
         */

        // Set your salt here, change it to meet your flavor:
        // The salt bytes must be at least 8 bytes.
        private byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}; //8 bytes

        public byte[] AES_Encrypt(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
        {
            byte[] encryptedBytes = null;

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    AES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

                    AES.KeySize = 256;
                    AES.BlockSize = 128;

                    var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);

                    AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                    AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

                    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
                        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                    }
                    encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }

            return encryptedBytes;
        }
    
        public byte[] AES_Decrypt(byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
        {
            byte[] decryptedBytes = null;

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    AES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

                    AES.KeySize = 256;
                    AES.BlockSize = 128;

                    var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
                    AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                    AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

                    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(bytesToBeDecrypted, 0, bytesToBeDecrypted.Length);
                        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                    }
                    decryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }

            return decryptedBytes;
        }

        public void Wipe()
        {
            Array.Clear(saltBytes, 0, saltBytes.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

note: the save and load functions are called with the exact same password

### The code that calls the encryption

```
public void Load(byte[] password)
    {
        Security decryptor = new Security();
        byte[] bytes = decryptor.AES_Decrypt(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Pathname()), password);

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            Root = (Folder)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
        Array.Clear(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        Array.Clear(password, 0, password.Length);
        decryptor.Wipe();
    }

    public void Save(byte[] password)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, Root);
            bytes = stream.ToArray();
        }

        Security encryptor = new Security();
        bytes = encryptor.AES_Encrypt(bytes, password);

        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Pathname(), bytes);
        Array.Clear(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        Array.Clear(password, 0, password.Length);
        encryptor.Wipe();
    }
```

### Code for testing key generation

```
static void keytests()
{
    byte[] passwordBytes = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    byte[] saltBytes = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    int iterations = 1000;

    var key1 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, iterations);
    var key2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, iterations);

    Console.WriteLine(BTS(key1.GetBytes(256 / 8)));
    Console.WriteLine(BTS(key2.GetBytes(256 / 8)));
}

public static string BTS(byte[] ba)
{
    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
    foreach (byte b in ba)
        hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
    return hex.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You should include the exception/error details

Comment: sorry, I meant to..fixed

Comment: Works fine for me: http://ideone.com/Ny9ezA. How are you calling this stuff?

Comment: It might be how you are using it.  It works fine for me.

Comment: this is how it is called http://pastebin.com/cp4yFige
when calling the save and load functions, i use the exact same password

Comment: Not because logic, because spam.  Links added.

Comment: right but its dumb how you need to make a good question to gain rep, but you need rep to make a better question

Comment: You are doing a lot of needless stuff and not doing other things that probably ought to be done.

Comment: Why are you using serialization? This is needlessly adding another layer to the code

Comment: can you encrypt a class without serializing it? if you look, on the load it casts it to a Folder, and thats what I am serializing. I dont think its unnecessary ;)

Comment: @Plutonix Like? give examples of both?

Comment: Presumably PaddingMode.None and PaddingMode.Zeros gave you different exceptions, though.  Either of them would solve this specific problem, since they aren't modes that remove padding.

Comment: no, the same exception in the same place still happened. i think lel. i tried a lot of different things. ill update tonight after work

Comment: Paddingmode.None gives the same error as PKCS7, but Zeros gives a different error, basically it decrypts it (improperly) and then the deserialization fails because it isnt the right byte array, garbled, etc

Comment: if this gets to 100 views and no attempted answers, im deleting it so i dont keep refreshing the page to check for one