Padding is invalid and cannot be removed while decrypting using AES
After updating from RijndaelManaged to AES, My code stopped working and throws exception 'Padding is invalid and cannot be removed'.
My Code used to work before when I used RijndaelManaged.
            // encryptedText comes as a post from another web application
            public static string DecryptStringAES(string encryptedText, string key)
            {
                var keybytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
                var iv = keybytes;

                var encryptStringToBytes = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(encryptedText, keybytes, iv);

// roundtrip value is same as enryptedText -- which came from another webapp.
                // Decrypt the bytes to a string.  here encryptStringToBytes is byte[80]
// this line does not throw the exception
                var roundtrip = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(encryptStringToBytes, keybytes, iv);

                //DECRYPT FROM CRIPTOJS
                var encrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(roundtrip);

                //here encryptStringToBytes is byte[48]
                //This Line throws the exception --Padding is invalid and cannot be removed
                var id = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(encrypted, keybytes, iv);

                return id;
            }
            
              private static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
            {
                if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0) throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
                if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0) throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
                if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0) throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

                string plaintext = null;

                try
                {
                    using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
                    {
                        aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
                        aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                        aesAlg.Key = Key;
                        aesAlg.IV = IV;

                        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                        {
                            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                            {
                                using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                                {
                                    plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string err = ex.Message;
                    throw;
                }

                return plaintext;
            }
            
             private static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
            {
                if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0) throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
                if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0) throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
                if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0) throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

                byte[] encrypted;

                try
                {
                    using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
                    {
                        aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
                        aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                        aesAlg.Key = Key;
                        aesAlg.IV = IV;

                        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                            {
                                using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                                {
                                    swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                                }

                                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string er = ex.Message;
                    throw ex;
                }

                return encrypted;
            }

If you look at my code, I have called **DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes ** Method twice.
First time when I called the method, the first parameter receives the byte[] of byte[80].This works as expected. and returns the string as I have expected.
           ` var roundtrip = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(encryptStringToBytes, keybytes, iv);`

on next line  after converting the string value that I have received  and passing it into the method for the second time. I get the exception.
I tried removing Padding or Mode, but that did not help.

You need to move the encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray(); outside of the using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469819/padding-is-invalid-and-cannot-be-removed-exception-while-decrypting-string-using/10470350#10470350

Also, note that the IV MUST be different each time you encrypt a message. Using the key is NOT OK! The IV can be public, but MUST be unique!

I'm slightly confused by your test. You take a base64-encoded string of encrypted data. You then encrypt that base64 string a second time, then decrypt it (back to the original base64 string), and that works OK. Then you base64-decode that string, and decrypt it again, and that fails. That implies that your base64-encoded ciphertext (the one passed into DecryptStringAES) doesn't have the correct padding. You haven't shared what that string is, however.

@canton7 base64  string value the second time the method generates, is the value in the db table which is  generated by another system, which use rijndaelmanaged. My methods used to use rijndaelmanaged  and used to get the result string from which  I can identified the record in the db table.

Also, these are the already existed codes in the program which I am working now. I do not have control over anything.

That's a bit confused, but I think you're saying that encryptedText comes from a database, and was created by a different system? Can you decrypt it without the round-tripping, i.e. var encrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);?

@canton7 encryptedText comes from the another webapplication as a post.  both of these web application used the shared secret key.

Could you answer my other question, please? Can you decrypt that without the round-tripping?

@canton7 I did not understand what you have asked me to do. This line of code does not throw exception.  var roundtrip = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(encryptStringToBytes, keybytes, iv);. The encryptedText which I get in the post method is the same as value of roundtrip.

Wait. You say that after round-tripping roundtrip is identical to encryptedText? But you also say that trying to decrypt roundtrip fails, but that trying to decrypt encryptedText succeeds? Those 3 statements can't all be true. Which one is wrong?

@canton7 if you checked my commented lines, only difference to the method is firsttime it receives byte[80] size value to the 'byte[] cypherText parameter' and second time, when I get bytes by converting from base64 string, byte size gets byte[48]. I am not sure  if its the problem and I am new to this. But everything still works if I switched back to the old method 'RijndaelManaged'

I'm getting contradictory information from you, which is why I ask for clarification. Now you're saying that roundtrip is not identical to encryptedText (they can't be identical if they have different lengths)? Then that's probably the problem in my deleted answer (and that @HansPassant spotted). I'll also ask again: does DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText), keybytes, iv); work or throw an exception? If that works then the that's probably the only problem; if that fails, something else is wrong too

CFB is implemented inconsistently (and sometimes buggy) across the different .NET versions. For instance, RijndaelManaged (on .NET) uses a default segment size of 128 bit, while Aes uses 8 bit. Try setting the segment size in EncryptStringToBytes_Aes() and DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes() to 128: aesAlg.FeedbackSize = 128 (preferably immediately after aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CFB).

@Topaco When I set the FeedbackSize to 128, It throws bad data exception in EncryptStringToBytes_Aes()

Which .NET version?

@canton7 I apologize, I wish  I could explain in better way.  I have commented the line which throws  the exception.

I don't see any recent edits? You could also my questions as "yes" or "no", which would really help.

@Topaco its .Net 4.8.

@canton7 I added few more comment in the code section.

As far as I know, .NET Framework does not support CFB128, only CFB8. If I interpret the comments in your code correctly, the encryption is done with CryptoJS. CryptoJS only supports CFB128, so switching to CFB8 is not an option. You could use BouncyCastle, which supports CFB128.

That's still unclear. "here encryptStringToBytes is byte[48]" -- I assume you mean "here encrypted is byte[48]"? Earlier you say "encryptStringToBytes is byte[80]", and a byte array can't change its length. I'm still asking the question: does DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText), keybytes, iv); work or throw an exception?

@canton7  yes, That throws the same exception

@Topaco another web application where user signs in has the same method that generate the id using  new RijndaelManaged(). I am trying to retrieve that id from this application which I am currently working on. This program also use new RijndaelManaged() and it works as expected. But since RijndaelManaged is obsolete I thought to change it Aes as suggested. While doing so I am getting that exception. I also have another program which in .net 6, I get the same error.

@canton7 so this is the line srDecrypt.ReadToEnd() which throws the exception

RijndaelManaged applies CFB-128 by default. On .NET Framework Aes only supports CFB-8. Either you stay with RijndaelManaged or you use a third party provider like BouncyCastle which supports CFB-128. On .NET 6, Aes also supports CFB-128 (since the default is CFB-8, you have to explicitly set aesAlg.FeedbackSize = 128).

For .NET Framework there is no way to use CFB-128 with the Aes implementation (stay with RijndaelManaged or apply BouncyCastle), with .NET 6 it is possible, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/JRMvNF.

@Topaco adding the FeedbackSize to 128 in .Net 6 worked. I guess  I will stay with RijndaelManaged for .Net Framework.
thank you

I really appreciate @canton7
